# Dynamically Adding Endpoints to a WCF Service hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I have a scenario where I would like to add endpoints dynamically.  I know this is completely possible if I write a self hosted WCF Service.

The basic idea of what I'm trying to do is to create a plug-gable WCF Host in IIS.  Based on available Exports I want to create Endpoints.  I am having a hard time figuring out where I can wire in to create the endpoints.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but you could write a custom ServiceHost and host it in IIS with a custom ServiceHostFactory - that would allow you (if I follow correctly) to do essentially the same thing as if you self-hosted the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own service host to use in IIS by using a custom `ServiceHostFactory`. In the .svc file you specify which factory you want to use, and in the factory code you can add as many endpoints as you wish.

You can find more information about service host factories and this scenario at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx.

Comment: I was able to basically do this but with the RoutingService.  I am using Routing also in this scenario which adds much more of a curveball.